# Parse and extract values from time format in python

Tags: python, strptime

I am trying to parse and extract values from my time data `2018-03-11 13:15:31.734874+01:00`.

I'm using `strptime()` to do this with the `%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z` format but I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2018-03-11 13:15:31.734874+01:00' does not match format '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'
```

Also, I don't know how to handle the `+1:00` in my time data. Can anyone help?

Comment: You have dashes `-` between the parts of your date, not spaces.

Comment: In what data structure, you have time data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here to solve.

First is the format string. It should be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z` to match exact date separators and timezone sequence (without space).

[From strftime and strptime Behavior:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-strptime-behavior)

> `%z` (lower case)     UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the object is naive).    (empty), +0000, -0400, +1030

Second is the colon (:) in timezone offset '+01:00'. That can be left out using substring: s[:-3]+s[-2:] or string substitute.

So the final answer is as below.

```py
from datetime import datetime
s = '2018-03-11 13:15:31.734874+01:00'
datetime.strptime(s[:-3]+s[-2:], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

Answer (score 0):

`%Y %m %d`  should be changed to `%Y-%m-%d` to match with the time string. Also, you need to remove the last `:` from the input to use with `%z`.

Here is how you should do:

```
import datetime
s = '2018-03-11 13:15:31.734874+01:00'
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join(s.rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'))

# 2018-03-11 13:15:31.734874+01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

#### At first:

`%Y %m %d` will not match `2018-03-11`. You need to adapt it to the time string! `%Y-%m-%d` instead should work.

#### Secondly:

**IF you are in python3**, the `%z` was added for time stamps. However the timestamp has to be without the colon, e.g. `+0100`instead of `+01:00`. Therefore, if you use python3 this works:

```
>>> time_string = '2018-03-11 13:15:31.734874+01:00'
>>> time_string = ''.join(time_string.rsplit(':', 1))

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 11, 13, 15, 31, 734874, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```

Btw the time_string after the editing looks like that:

```
>>> time_string
'2018-03-11 13:15:31.734874+0100'
```

---

**IF you are in python2**, the `%z` won't work, here you have to use the parse function of the dateutil module, which is straight forward.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('2018-03-11 13:15:31.734874+01:00')
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 11, 13, 15, 31, 734874, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```